# Trouble with MYSQL joins and count

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I have two tables, **X** and **Y**

**X:**

- x_id
- type_id
- user_id
- description

**Y:**

- x_id (not unique)
- date

I supply a user_id and a type_id, each user can have several entries in X with the same type_id.

I need to count all the entries in Y that match the criteria above. (hopefully I made myself clear ;))

So basically: From entries on X that match a user_id and type_id, grab all entries on Y that have the same x_id.

This is a query I was attempting in CodeIgniter (but any sort of MYSQL would be fine):

```
  $this->db->select("X.description, COUNT(Y.x_id) AS count ");
    $this->db->from("X");
    $this->db->join("Y", "Y.x_id=X.x_id");
    $this->db->where("X.type_id", 1);
    $this->db->where("X.user_id", 2);
```

This is only returning me 1 entry though.

Comment: If you need the count for each `X.description` you'll need to `GROUP BY X.description`, but I'm not sure how that's done in CodeIgniter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on this "I need to count all the entries in Y that match the criteria above " you can try this:

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(*) 
FROM 
    x 
INNER JOIN y
    ON x.x_id = y.x_id
WHERE 
    x.type_id = 1
    AND x.user_id = 2
```

**UPDATE:** If you want to count per description you need to group by it as mentioned by  ***Ed Gibbs***:

```
SELECT 
    x.description,
    COUNT(*) 
FROM 
    x 
INNER JOIN y
    ON x.x_id = y.x_id
WHERE 
    x.type_id = 1
    AND x.user_id = 2
GROUP BY
    x.description
```

Comment: Leave it to me to forget the groupby.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this code:

```
select count(x_id) as total from y where x_id in ( select x_id from x where type_id = 'type_id_here' AND user_id = 'user_id_here'  )
```

In Codeigniter:

```
<?php
 $sql = "select count(x_id) as total from y where x_id in ( select x_id from x where type_id = 'type_id_here' AND user_id = 'user_id_here'  )";
 $rs = $this->db->query($sql);
 $data = $rs->row_array();
 $total = $data['total'];
?>
```